# Terminator won't open with default profile

Tags: gnome-terminator

Below is my `Terminator` profile. I wanted it to, always, open any shell and window with the light profile.

If I'm not wrong, using the configurations below should make it open with the light profile by default, but it does not!

How do I make it use the "light" profile by default?

```
[global_config]
[keybindings]
  new_tab = <Ctrl>n
  next_tab = <Ctrl>Right
  split_vert = <Ctrl>v
  split_horiz = <Ctrl>h
  prev_tab = <Ctrl>Left
[profiles]
  [[light]]
    palette = "#073642:#d30102:#859900:#b58900:#6c71c4:#d33682:#2aa198:#839496:#586e75:#cb4b16:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#dc322f:#2aa198:#93a1a1"
    use_system_font = False
    cursor_color = "#002b36"
    foreground_color = "#002b36"
    show_titlebar = False
    background_color = "#eee8d5"
  [[dark]]
    palette = "#073642:#d30102:#859900:#b58900:#6c71c4:#d33682:#2aa198:#839496:#586e75:#cb4b16:#859900:#b58900:#268bd2:#dc322f:#2aa198:#93a1a1"
    use_system_font = False
    cursor_color = "#eee8d5"
    foreground_color = "#eee8d5"
    show_titlebar = False
    background_color = "#002b36"
[layouts]
    [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = light
    [[[window0]]]
      profile = light
      type = Window
      parent = ""
[plugins]
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the terminator is not opening with the "light" profile. How can i do this??

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the terminator like
`terminator -p light`
or
 `terminator --profile=light`

An easier way to do this would be to make a Bash/Zsh alias like this:
`alias terminator="terminator --profile=light"`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/preferences.html#profiles)

> Re-use profiles for new terminals (default: off)
>
> ```
> When creating a new terminal with splitting or new tabs, 
> if this is enabled, then the profile from the previously 
> focussed terminal will also be used for the new one.
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as the layouts includes profiles selection, you can run terminator with

```
terminator -l child1
```

If you don't want to do this, you have to set you default profile inside the "default" layout

```
[layouts]
    [[default]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      profile = light
```